# Form submit takes to Search page

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

Any idea why submitted form data loads the search.php page instead of submitting form?

URL: http://domain/contact-us/

On form submission it redirects to: http://domain/?s=&wpforms%5Bfields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfirst%5D=iuiou&wpforms%5Bfields%5D%5B0%5D%5Blast%5D=uoiu&wpforms%5Bfields%5D%5B1%5D=amigoow%40yahoo.com&wpforms%5Bfields%5D%5B6%5D=General+Feedback&wpforms%5Bfields%5D%5B3%5D=7987&wpforms%5Bfields%5D%5B2%5D=ou&wpforms%5Bhp%5D=&wpforms%5Bid%5D=87632&wpforms%5Bnonce%5D=df749058ef&_wp_http_referer=%2Fcontact-us%2F&wpforms%5Bsubmit%5D=wpforms-submit

I have changed the plugin from ContactForm7 to WPForms but it turns out it's something not related to plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your form opening tag looks like this:

```
<form method="get" action="http://newdev.propakistani.pk" role="search">
```

So its doing exactly as per this tag. You need to amend action to the URL of the php file that processes the form.